# Wrong auto layout MKMapView

Tags: autolayout, mkmapview, mapkit

I need to allocate MKMapView programmatically and when i flip couple times device - it resizes wrong, for example this green annotation must be in center of view, but it higher, and MKAttributionLabel have wrong frame
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like MapKit bug. You can file bugs on Apple Framework at https://bugreport.apple.com